# How to properly mask/redirect urls in apache httpd?

Tags: url, apache

I have one apache httpd server running on a hostname:

firsthostname

I have another apache httpd server running on another hostname:

secondhostname

I want to make it such that whenever someone goes to:

firsthostname, it redirects to secondhostname. If the user goes to firsthostname/something, what the user actually sees is the as if the user went to "secondhostname/something", though the "secondhostname" is masked

What and how do I configure this on the httpd installed on "firsthostname"? I am running on a windows machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using apache rewrite or apache redirect

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule    ^/foo  /bar
```

Or

```
Redirect /foo.html /bar.html
```

Check out this [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html)

Comment: Where specifically in the httpd.conf file does this go in? Or does this go into some htaccess?

Comment: You have to configure virtual host in httpd

Answer (score 0):

You will need a `DNS` server. You can then simply setup a `CNAME` record to map `firsthostname` to `secondhostname`.